# Переменное число параматров

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. Кто сможет объяснить мне данный пример?:

```
def total(initial=10, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count


print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, set=50, settings=200))
```

Вывод соответственно: 284. Вопрос: куда делся параметр `initial=10`, почему он не берётся в расчёты? Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно записали принимающие функцией `total` параметры. Сразу пишем `позиционные` параметры, потом `ключевые`.

```
def total(*numbers, initial=10, **keywords):
    count = initial
    print(count, numbers, keywords)    
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, set=50, settings=200))
```

---

```
10 (10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10) {'set': 50, 'settings': 200}
294
```

Вставьте `print(count, numbers, keywords)` в свой пример и посмотрите что получается.

---

аналог выше написанного примера:

```
def total(*numbers, **keywords):
    count = 0
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, set=50, settings=200, initial=10))
294
```

Comment: Ну это понятно, но всё ещё вопрос тот же. Почему так, куда делся тот параметр? Может return его убрал, ведь данный оператор останавливает функцию и может то что указано return count и из-за этого intial пропал?

Comment: @Evgeniy вы неправильно записали принимающие функцией `total` параметры. Сразу пишем позиционные параметры, потом ключевые!

Comment: @Evgeniy я добавил в пример некоторые пояснения.

Comment: Надо вставить данные слова в свой пример?

Comment: Если так, тогда получается ошибка.

Comment: А 10 перед кортежем что означает у Вас?

Comment: `print(count, numbers, keywords)`  -> `10  (10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10)  {'set': 50, 'settings': 200}` 10 перед кортежем это `count`

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то `10+1+2+3+8+10+50+200` действительно `284`, так что вроде бы всё работает.

https://ideone.com/7gLryS

Comment: `initial=10` а `count = initial`  `10 + 10+1+2+3+8+10+50+200 = 294`

Comment: Если мой пример использовать, да действительно получается 284, а если перенести initial - 294 и так.

Comment: Ну так первый аргумент и есть initial.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pythontutor.com - вы можете использовать это для визуализации и понимания того, что и когда присваивается.
https://github.com/cool-RR/PySnooper - так же очень удобный инструмент для дебага.
[вот здесь мой пример, как им(PySnooper) пользоваться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513765/print-method-to-print-passed-expression-literally-along-with-computed-output-f/57649055?stw=2#57649055)

```
In [4]: print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, set=50, settings=200))                                                                                                                                                  
Source path:... <ipython-input-3-f2a7a77a0f64>
Starting var:.. initial = 10
Starting var:.. numbers = (1, 2, 3, 8, 10)
Starting var:.. keywords = {'set': 50, 'settings': 200}
11:03:23.581967 call         2 def total(initial=10, *numbers, **keywords):
11:03:23.582117 line         3     count = initial
New var:....... count = 10
11:03:23.582151 line         4     for number in numbers:
New var:....... number = 1
11:03:23.582191 line         5         count += number
Modified var:.. count = 11
11:03:23.582226 line         4     for number in numbers:
Modified var:.. number = 2
11:03:23.582293 line         5         count += number
Modified var:.. count = 13
11:03:23.582340 line         4     for number in numbers:
Modified var:.. number = 3
11:03:23.582374 line         5         count += number
Modified var:.. count = 16
11:03:23.582435 line         4     for number in numbers:
Modified var:.. number = 8
11:03:23.582486 line         5         count += number
Modified var:.. count = 24
11:03:23.582532 line         4     for number in numbers:
Modified var:.. number = 10
11:03:23.582564 line         5         count += number
Modified var:.. count = 34
11:03:23.582648 line         4     for number in numbers:
11:03:23.582694 line         6     for key in keywords:
New var:....... key = 'set'
11:03:23.582724 line         7         count += keywords[key]
Modified var:.. count = 84
11:03:23.582762 line         6     for key in keywords:
Modified var:.. key = 'settings'
11:03:23.582799 line         7         count += keywords[key]
Modified var:.. count = 284
11:03:23.582846 line         6     for key in keywords:
11:03:23.582894 line         8     return count
11:03:23.582923 return       8     return count
Return value:.. 284
284
```

В общем PySnooper вывел вот такой результат для вашего примера.
В вашу функцию передаются такие параметры, как

```
initial = 10
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 8, 10)
keywords = {'set': 50, 'settings': 200}
```

поэтому и такой результат.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Всё понятно.

Comment: @Evgeniy если вы считаете, что это ответ на ваш вопрос, то нажмите стрелку вверх напротив и на птичку тоже можно нажать =)

Comment: Добро. Уже сделано.;)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, достаточно упростить пример, и посмотреть какие аргументы получает функция

```
def total(initial=10, *numbers):
    return initial, numbers
```

не передали аргументов - используется по умолчанию initial=10

```
print(total())  # (10, ()) ~ initial=10, numbers=()
```

передали один аргумент - он попадет в initial, т.к. это первый аргумент

```
print(total(2))  # (2, ()) ~ initial=2, numbers=()
```

передали более одного аргумента - первый попадет в initial, т.к. это первый аргумент, а остаток аргументов запишется в numbers

```
print(total(3, 4, 5))  # (3, (4, 5,)) ~ initial=3, numbers=(4, 5,)
```

Comment: Тоже благодарю за ответ.